# Invariant subspaces in Lie groups and algebras representations

Tags: differential-geometry, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, invariant-subspace

I am trying to prove the following statement:

> Let $G$ be a connected Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ and with a representation $\Phi: G \to \text{GL}(V)$, with $V$ finite-dimensional. Then, $\Phi$ induces a unique representation $\varphi: \mathfrak g \to \text{End}(V)$ of the Lie algebra and a subspace of $V$ is $G$-invariant if and only if it is $\mathfrak g$-invariant."

Could you give some references or any proof? I know there are several entries in this forum about it, but I don't see one which helped me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The representation $\Phi$ of $G$ induces a representation of $\mathfrak g$ defined as follows: if $X\in\mathfrak g$ and $v\in V$, then$$\varphi(X)(v)=\left.\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\right|_{t=0}\Phi\bigl(\exp(tX)\bigr)(v).$$It is clear from this definition that if $W$ is a subspace of $V$ which is $G$-invariant, then it is also $\mathfrak g$-invariant. And, if $W$ is $\mathfrak g$-invariant, and if $v\in W$, then\begin{align}\Phi\bigl(\exp(X)\bigr)(v)&=\exp\bigl(\varphi(X)\bigr)(v)\\&=v+\varphi(X)(v)+\frac1{2!}\varphi(X)\bigl(\varphi(X)(v)\bigr)+\cdots\\&\in W.\end{align}Since $G$ is connected, $G$ is spanned by its elements of the form $\exp(X)$ ($X\in\mathfrak g$), from which it follows that $W$ is $G$-invariant.