# Irreducible representations of the identity component of the Spin group

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, connectedness, spin-geometry

Let $Spin(p,q)$ be the real spin group to the quadratic space $\mathbb{R}^{p,q}$ defined via Clifford algebras as $Pin(\mathbb{R}^{p,q}) \cap Cl^0(\mathbb{R}^{p,q})$, meaning as the subset of the Clifford algebra which is generated by an even number of elements $v \in \mathbb{R}^{p,q}$ with $Q(v) = \pm 1$, where $Q$ denotes the quadratic form.

Ultimately, in physics we are interested in the irreducible representations of the identity component of the spin group $Spin_0(p,q)$. Now, I would like to understand whether the restriction of an irreducible spinor representation (Induced by the restriction of a representation of the Clifford algebra) of $Spin(p,q)$ remains irreducible.

I tried to prove that an additive basis of the even subalgebra $Cl^0(\mathbb{R}^{p,q})$ is contained in $Spin_0(p,q)$ by showing that the image of the basis under the adjoint representation lies in the identity component $SO_0(p,q)$ of the special orthogonal group, but that did not seem to work.

Could someone prove that these representations remain irreducible or give me a counterexample? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Yes restrictions to the identity component preserve irreducibility. There might be a more direct way (by which I mean only talking about groups) but you could prove it easily by moving to the Lie algebra representation and back and the Lie algebra doesn't care about other components anyway.

Comment: @Callum , thank you for the quick reply! I do not know how representations of a Lie group are related to representations of its Lie algebra (Even though the other direction is clear for simply connected groups). Is there a one to one map of representations of any Lie group to representations of its Lie algebra? If so, could you recommend books / lecture notes which discuss that?

Comment: Sorry I've thought about this some more and I think I was wrong. You can create simple counter examples by taking multiple copies of an irrep of the Lie algebra (or connected component) and then requiring that an element in the other component swaps these copies. The true fact is that the irreps of the connected component all correspond to irreps of the Lie algebra (if the component is simply connected this covers all the Lie algebra reps as well) which you can see proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3944808/invariant-subspaces-in-lie-groups-and-algebras-representations)